# Change Typo Column Values with Right Word based on Columns in Other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, similarity, fuzzy-comparison

I have two dataframe, the first one is location ,

```
location = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['RIYADH','SEOUL','BUSAN','TOKYO','OSAKA'],
                    'country': ['Saudi Arabia','South Korea','South Korea','Japan','Japan']})
```

the other one is customer,

```
customer = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1001,2002,3003,4004,5005,6006,7007,8008,9009],
                        'city': ['tokio','Sorth KOREA','riadh','JAPANN','tokyo','osako','Arab Saudi','SEOUL','buSN']})
```

I want to change the typo word in location column in customer dataframe with the right one in city/country from location dataframe. So the output will be like this:

```
id    location
1001  TOKYO
2002  South Korea
3003  RIYADH
4004  Japan
5005  TOKYO
6006  OSAKA
7007  Saudi Arabia
8008  SEOUL
9009  BUSAN
```

Comment: This is a good question. Conflating city with country is a bit odd. I recommend you ask a simpler question, which focuses on just `city`. (It's simple enough to create a list of 6 words, 3 from city column and 3 from country column. It's the subsequent translation via fuzzy match that is the interesting aspect.)

Comment: I edited my question, the city in customer dataframe is more like location, cause sometimes customer fill it not with their cities but their countries, so if the location in customer data not match with city column in the location, it will search match word in country column in location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, based on [`RapidFuzz`](https://pypi.org/project/rapidfuzz/):

```
from rapidfuzz import process

out = (customer.assign(
    aux = customer['city']
    .map(lambda x: 
        process.extractOne(x, location['city']+'*'+location['country'])[0])))

out[['aux1', 'aux2']] = out['aux'].str.split(r'\*', expand=True)
out['city'] = out.apply(lambda x: 
    process.extractOne(x['city'], x.loc['aux1':'aux2'])[0], axis=1)
out = out.drop(columns=['aux', 'aux1', 'aux2'])
```

Output:

```
     id          city
0  1001         TOKYO
1  2002   South Korea
2  3003        RIYADH
3  4004         Japan
4  5005         TOKYO
5  6006         OSAKA
6  7007  Saudi Arabia
7  8008         SEOUL
8  9009         BUSAN
```

**EDIT**

This tries to offer a solution for the OP's below comment:

```
from rapidfuzz import process

def get_match(x, y, score):
    match = process.extractOne(x, y)
    return np.nan if match[1] < score else match[0]

out = (customer.assign(
    aux=customer['city']
    .map(lambda x:
         process.extractOne(x, location['city']+'*'+location['country'])[0])))

out[['aux1', 'aux2']] = out['aux'].str.split(r'\*', expand=True)
out['city'] = out.apply(lambda x: get_match(
    x['city'], x.loc['aux1':'aux2'], 92), axis=1)
out = out.drop(columns=['aux', 'aux1', 'aux2'])
```

Output:

```
     id   city
0  1001    NaN
1  2002    NaN
2  3003    NaN
3  4004    NaN
4  5005  TOKYO
5  6006    NaN
6  7007    NaN
7  8008  SEOUL
8  9009    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question. I want the country name still same cause there is a lot of other city with same country in the data.

Comment: Please, @Arthur, see my updated solution.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, may I ask you how if I want to limit the treshold? For example if the score < 92 then the value will become NULL or 'Unknown Location'

Comment: I am a bit confused, @Arthur, as in data of your question there is no `score` variable.

Comment: I mean the ration, out['city'] = out.apply(lambda x: 
    process.extractOne(x['city'], x.loc['aux1':'aux2'])[1], axis=1) there is ratio right? cmiiw

Comment: OK, @Arthur, understood now. Please, see my edited solution.